# Facing Memory Issues with Apache FOP (Currently using 2.5 Version)

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-leaks, apache-fop

In our Project we are using Apache FOP 2.5 version to generate PRN and PDF Files,
Observed that the Project is occupying more heap memory and encountering memory issues.

Maven Dependency added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  
          <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
          <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Java Code snippet generating prn using Apache FOP

```
Public void generateFile(){

OutputStream outStream = new java..io.BufferedOutputStream(new java.io.FileOutputStream(<outputFilePath>,true));
FopFactory fopFactory= FopFactory.newInstance(new File(XslFIle).toURI());
FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
foUserAgent.setTargetResolution(600);
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Template template = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(xslFile));
String mType = fopFactory.newFop(mType,foUserAgent,outStream);
Transormer transformer = template.newTransformer();
Source src = new StreamSource(xmlFile);
Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
transformer.transform(<src>,<res>);
if(outStream != null)
outStream.close():
}
```

When I try to analyze the HeapDump there is one leak suspected with java.awt.BufferdImage which is using internally by FOP.

Any Suggestions and help is appreciated, planning to upgrade Apache FOP will it be helpful ?